# I encountered the following error when using the trained model

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision

```
# import libraries
import torch
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load the trained ResNet model
from torch.autograd import Variable

model = torch.load("model.pth")
model.eval()

# load the image of the steel pipe
image = cv2.imread("img/75.jpg")
DEVICE = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# preprocess the image
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # convert to RGB
image_resized = cv2.resize(image_rgb, (224, 224)) # resize to 224x224
image_normalized = image_resized / 255.0 # normalize to [0, 1]
image_tensor = torch.from_numpy(image_normalized) # convert to tensor
image_tensor = image_tensor.permute(2, 0, 1) # change the order of channels
image_tensor = image_tensor.unsqueeze(0) # add a batch dimension
data = Variable(image_tensor).to(DEVICE)

# pass the image tensor to the model and get the output
print(image)
output = model([image_tensor])

# get the predicted bounding boxes, labels, scores, and masks
boxes = output["boxes"].detach().numpy()
labels = output["labels"].detach().numpy()
scores = output["scores"].detach().numpy()
masks = output["masks"].detach().numpy()


# filter out the objects that are not steel pipes
threshold = 0.5 # you can adjust this value
indices = np.where((labels == 1) & (scores >= threshold))[0] # assuming label 1 is for steel pipe
boxes = boxes[indices]
masks = masks[indices]

# draw the bounding boxes and masks on the original image
for box, mask in zip(boxes, masks):
    # get the coordinates of the box
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.astype(int)
    # get the mask for the object
    mask = mask.squeeze()
    # resize the mask to match the original image size
    mask = cv2.resize(mask, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))
    # apply a threshold to binarize the mask
    mask = (mask > 0.5).astype(np.uint8)
    # create a color for the mask
    color = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=3)
    color = [int(c) for c in color]
    # draw the bounding box on the image
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, 2)
    # draw the mask on the image
    image[mask == 1] = cv2.addWeighted(image[mask == 1], 0.5, np.array(color), 0.5, 0)

# save or display the resulting image
cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", image)
cv2.imshow("Result", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

error：
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\MASTER_Project\testModel.py", line 27, in <module>
output = model([image_tensor])
File "D:\MASTER_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\MASTER_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\resnet.py", line 285, in forward
return self._forward_impl(x)
File "D:\MASTER_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\resnet.py", line 268, in _forward_impl
x = self.conv1(x)
File "D:\MASTER_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\MASTER_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 463, in forward
return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
File "D:\MASTER_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 459, in _conv_forward
return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
TypeError: conv2d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (list, Parameter, NoneType, tuple, tuple, tuple, int), but expected one of:

- (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
  didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!list of [Tensor]!, !Parameter!, !NoneType!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, int)
- (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, str padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
  didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!list of [Tensor]!, !Parameter!, !NoneType!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, int)

How can I correct the code?

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass list to the `model` call, pass tensor:

```
output = model(image_tensor.to(DEVICE))
```

While `image_normalized.dtype==np.float64` you highly likely will face the following error 'RuntimeError: expected scalar type Double but found Float' (depending on what model you trying to load). To fix it call `.float()` method on tensor. As result you should have something like:

```
input_tensor = image_tensor.to(DEVICE).float()
output = model(input_tensor)
```